# How do you input/store URLs in custom theme settings in Bigcommerce?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm working on making a custom theme and it appears that text settings defined in the schema.json have a max input length of 65 characters. I don't see any documentation to that effect, but whenever I enter more than 65 characters into a text field setting, I get an error while previewing/saving. I assume this is intentional behavior.

I'm trying to make settings where the input is a URL and URLs are often longer than 65 characters. I can conceive of a number of janky workaround for this problem, but I was hoping to find out if there is some officially supported solution for URL based theme settings, or if I just have to go my own way for now by mis-using lang strings, breaking URLs into multiple settings, or hard-code URLs into HTML templates.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't missing anything here. There is no "url" schema option. The "text" schema option is limited to 64 characters (whether this is intentional or not, I'm not sure).

However, URL's should not typically be longer than 65 characters (if they are relative URL's). You should be able to accomplish all functionality you need with the relative URL (without the domain), no?

Another alternative is to rely on the pages or categories loop that is available on all pages of the store. You could make a setting (id = category_name) with the field label "Link to this category", then they could enter "Shirts", then your code could be:

```
{{#each categories}}
{{#if name '===' ../theme_settings.category_name}}
<a href="{{url}}">Link</a>
{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

This assumes they are entering a top-level category. Anyway, hope this clears some things up for you!